# What would have happened if Cedric had taken the Triwizard Cup first?

Tags: harry-potter

Supposing Cedric had agreed when Harry urged him to take the Triwizard Cup-what then?

Voldemort's only need for the cup was as a portkey specifically to take Harry to him.
Would Cedric have just been able to take the cup normally and leave Voldemort hanging out in the graveyard,waiting for Harry to turn up?

Or would it have activated whoever touched it,leaving Voldemort rather annoyed when Cedric turned up,instead of the Harry he was expecting?

Comment: He would have killed Cedric and continued waiting for Harry.

Comment: @Valorum Albeit with no way of getting Harry to LH. The Portkey would've been used already and there'd be no way of getting it back to the middle of the maze.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Wasn't it a Two-way portkey? Given that Harry used it to get back?

Comment: @Aegon How would he return the portkey, though? He or a Death Eater would have to go back with it. Sure, they could do that, kill Harry and bring his dead body back to LH, but how would they know Harry was near the Cup's original location in the maze?

Comment: @tobiasvl Why would he have to go back or send someone along? He would have had cedric right there. He could cast imperius curse on him and send him back to get Harry. He took a chance with the whole plan, why not take a chance on hopinh that Cedric would find Harry?

Comment: @Aegon Yeah, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 17):

### It would've transported Cedric to Little Hangleton by himself.

The Portkey was simply bewitched so that whoever touched it first would be transported to the graveyard at Little Hangleton. It didn't differentiate between different people; it would've worked regardless of whether it was Harry or Cedric who was touching it.

> “He asked me whether I was ready to risk everything for him. I was ready. It was my dream, my greatest ambition, to serve him, to prove myself to him. He told me he needed to place a faithful servant at Hogwarts. A servant who would guide Harry Potter through the Triwizard Tournament without appearing to do so. A servant who would watch over Harry Potter. Ensure he reached the Triwizard Cup. Turn the cup into a Portkey, which would **take the first person to touch it** to my master."
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35, Veritaserum)*.</sub>

Clearly, Crouch Junior intended that Harry would touch the Cup first. His strategy, as the quote above shows, was to clear the way for Harry by attacking the other competitors from outside the maze. His goal was to get Harry to the Cup which he was successful in doing, even if he hadn't counted on Harry and Cedric helping each other out as much as they did. If Cedric had touched the Cup by himself then he would've been transported by himself and the plan would've failed.

Comment: Or Voldemort could use imperius curse on Cedric, make him take the Portkey back and bring Harry Along with him? HowBowDah?

Comment: @Aegon Yeah, I suppose he could've.

Comment: @Aegon I don't think that would necessarily work. When Harry grabs the cup again, it transports him to the entrance of the maze. So an Imperius'd Cedric would just appear to have won the Tournament by showing up at the entrance.

Answer (score 1):

They’d have probably used cedrics blood, but then Harry wouldn’t have seen the priory incantatum, the dark lord wouldn’t have Harry’s mothers protection along with him

Which changes a lot of things, I still think Harry’s body would reject the possession in part 5, but when it comes to deathly hallows, Harry can only come back if he and the dark lord shared the protection, so Harry would have had to win the duel in the forest rather then his sacrifice

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was basically about what happens in the moment when Cedric touches the cup first.  The rest, how Voldemort and company would react, is both completely speculative and beyond the scope of the question.